# Limiting the number of login attempts

Tags: ios

I have an application in which there is a login screen. I want to add a feature in my application that is limiting the maximum number of login attempts at a time. For example, if a user tries to login with wrong `user name` and/or `password` more than 5 times, then a message should pop up that you can't login for the next 60 secs. If he tries within that 60 secs, then he should not be able to login. After 60 secs, he should be able to do so with the right password.

Comment: What do you have so far? Is there a server that should be rejecting these logins? Do you limit the number of attempts and need a way to let users login again later?

Answer (score 0):

Should be as simple as creating an instance variable int and incrementing it after each failed login, if it hits 5 prevent login attempt and at same time fire an NSTimer to wipe the count to 0 after 60 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Save the last time a failed attempt was made and the attempt count in the defaults.

Comment: yeah! I was also suggested by somebody to use NSUserDefaults but I don't know how to implement that. So, can u please show me with the help of an example. Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are a million tutorials and info posts on the web and SO - here is one: http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-tutorials/106311-tutorial-1-how-to-use-nsuserdefault.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use an NSTimer to enforce the time limits.
In a simple case you increment a counter each time a login attempt is unsuccessful.
On the 6th attempt you set a flag to NO, and start a timer.
Any further attempts while the flag is at NO are rejected.
When the timer fires it starts the flag to YES and the user may retry.

Answer (score 0):

Just as a concept:

```
start a session for the login process if there is none;
setting up the timer in that session (startime) if not already set

loop by post to self:

    check login;

    on unsuccessfull login:

        counting unsuccessfull logins;
        if timer / counter are hit, instead of presenting the login fields, 
        show an error message;
        if time of no login is reached, show login fields again, reset counter;
        return;

    on successfull login:

        stop and drop the current session (to get rid of the timer stuff);
        start the real session;
        forward to application screen;
```

But:
this will not prevent anyone from brute-force your app since this all depends on a session cookie. Usually these bf attacks don't return any cookies, so they will always start a new session with a very first attempt. Much effort, no effect. Relying on IP addresses is as well not helping, if you are hit by bot net you will get 100s of requests from various IPs per second.

I would recommend to have something *like* a [CSRF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) Token in the login window/screen

Answer (score 0):

If your login comes from a service, it's best to handle it there. Anything you put into NSUserDefaults can be read and potentially altered.